# Is anyone has idea about Palm line detection in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, edge-detection, imagefilter

Currently, I am doing Image COLOUR filtering operation second MEDIAN filtering then CANNY EDGE DETECTION ALGORITHM.

Then, I read pixels using for loop and I draw lines using pixel, but I do not getting proper result for palm scanning and showing lines on human Palm.

So if anybody has any types of idea regarding this then please let me know.

Currently i am getting this type of result:
[image] 
but I need this type of output:
[image]

Comment: Sharing some code snippets or process information will make people to suggest more information regarding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got your problem, You can do this by following steps.

1.process your hand image with canny edge detection algo lets name that **cannyImage**.

2.now create the bitmap of cannyImage and remove black pixels from the image and replace them with transparent pixels, black only because canny image will be filled with black color and objects lines in white when you process the image through the algo, now you have extracted the image with palm lines white in color, lets name that **palmLineImage**.

3.now the main part is **MASKING**  you need to mask the palmLineImage on the original image.

These three steps will give you your desire O/P.

Tools you can use **GPUImage** awsesome library by BradLarson for this  https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2

For refining the palm image from background which I'm sure you have to use in future you can use **GrabCut algo**

LINK - https://github.com/naver/grabcutios

and now the apple has launched Photos captured in Portrait Mode on iOS 12 contain an embedded person segmentation matte that made it easy to create creative visual effects like background replacement.
Links  - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/260/ , https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/225/

Comment: Hello Shivam, Thanks for your valuable time and answer. I already perform all these steps which you suggest me, but  i am not able to detect lines of palm after perfoming Canny Edge Detection algorithm.

Comment: what are you using for performing the algo ?, if you are using gpuimage then it has sobel edge detection also which can help you

Comment: also you need to configure threshold parameter correctly, while using the canny edge algo (play with it and get your o/p) and if you need help with that then also let me know i've worked on something similar

Comment: I used GPUImage for Canny Edge Detection algorithm, as per your suggestion i will try to set threshold and lets check what i get. If i need further help, then i will let you know about that, thank you.

Comment: Hello Shivam, is it possible to share your contact number or email id with me? So we can get more discuss about this.

Comment: how can i draw line on pixel?

And how can i draw different color line as Parth Vaghasiya did above?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use something like the douglas peucker algorithm - to simplify the number of data points and smooth the lines. link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm